# How to change Entry height in tkinter while using grid system and add text wraping?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm making an email sending gui application. I want to add an entry (messageEntry in my code) for entering the message. I want to change it's height so the message doesn't have to be entered in one line (I want to have text wraping). I tried using ipady, it does resize the entry but the message can still only be entered in one line (in the middle of the entry). Here is my code:

```
def sendMail(senderEmail, senderPassword):

    global server

    sendMailFont = ['Consolas', 10]

    sendMailWindow = Tk()

    sendMailWindow.title("Sendmail")

    sendMailWindow.resizable(False, False)
    sendMailWindow.focus_force()

    # sendMailWindow.iconbitmap('info icon.ico')
    sendMailWindow.config(bg = "#DCDCDC")

    loggedInLabel = Label(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), text = "Logged in as {}".format(senderEmail), bg = "#DCDCDC")
    loggedInLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    subjectLabel = Label(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), text = "Subject", bg = "#DCDCDC")
    subjectLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "w")

    subjectEntry = Entry(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), bg = "#FFFFFF", width = 37)
    subjectEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "w", ipady = 2)

    messageLabel = Label(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), text = "Message", bg = "#DCDCDC")
    messageLabel.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = "w")

    messageEntry = Entry(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), bg = "#FFFFFF", width = 37)
    messageEntry.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = "w")

    hiddenLabel = Label(sendMailWindow, font = ('Consolas', 1), text = "", bg = "#DCDCDC")
    hiddenLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "we")
    hiddenLabel = Label(sendMailWindow, font = ('Consolas', 10), text = "", bg = "#DCDCDC")
    hiddenLabel.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = "we")

    sendMailWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: And entry widget can only be one line. If you want more lines, use `Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tkinter.scrolledtext` module like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

def sendMail(senderEmail, senderPassword):

    global server

    sendMailFont = ['Consolas', 10]

    sendMailWindow = Tk()

    sendMailWindow.title("Sendmail")

    sendMailWindow.resizable(False, False)
    sendMailWindow.focus_force()

    # sendMailWindow.iconbitmap('info icon.ico')
    sendMailWindow.config(bg = "#DCDCDC")

    loggedInLabel = Label(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), text = "Logged in as {}".format(senderEmail), bg = "#DCDCDC")
    loggedInLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    subjectLabel = Label(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), text = "Subject", bg = "#DCDCDC")
    subjectLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "w")

    subjectEntry = Entry(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), bg = "#FFFFFF", width = 37)
    subjectEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "w", ipady = 2)

    messageLabel = Label(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), text = "Message", bg = "#DCDCDC")
    messageLabel.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = "w")

    ##########
    messageEntry = ScrolledText(sendMailWindow, font = (sendMailFont), bg = "#FFFFFF", width = 37, height = 5)
    messageEntry.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = "w")
    ##########


    sendMailWindow.mainloop()
```

This module is the `tkinter.text` module with a scroll bar. You can adjust his height.

Comment: Tip: use `\ ` for cut your lines of code and so render them more visible. Example: `codecodecode\ [next line] codecodecode`

Comment: How can I get the content from messageEntry when using ScrolledText?

Comment: You can use `messageEntry.get(1.0, "end")` for getting the entire message.